# Is this MySql Query Statement correct?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know whether this MySql statement will be executed correctly,

```
"SELECT sum(price) FROM products WHERE productid IN (SELECT productid FROM shoppingcart WHERE sessionid=".$this->$sessionid.")"
```

And if not please give me pointers as to where I am wrong.

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you are using PHP, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you meant

```
$this->sessionid
```

not

```
$this->$sessionid
```

(the second one returns value of property, which name is stored in sessionid, thus, when $sessionid is 'abcdef', it tries to return value of $this->abcdef property).

Also, enclose in ' AND escape all parameters.

```
"SELECT sum(price) FROM products WHERE productid IN (SELECT productid FROM shoppingcart WHERE sessionid='".mysql_escape_string($this->sessionid)."')";
```

Answer (score 1):

i am using sql server but i think error over here is

single quote ' is required for session id

```
        "SELECT sum(price) FROM products WHERE productid IN (SELECT productid 
    FROM shoppingcart WHERE sessionid='".$this->$sessionid."')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

As @praynay said, I believe you need quotes around the session id.

Also, be **very, very sure** `$this->sessionid` will not have a quote character *in itself*, or that you escape it properly before passing it to MySQL. (Or better yet, use a parameterized query.)